# Deploying (gpo) local TCP/IP printers to users who are not local admin

Tags: group-policy, deployment, printing

I'm trying to deploy local TCP/IP printers to users who are not local admin using GPO.
However, because they are not local admin they do not have the rights to install printers and thus the printers are not being added when the group policy is run.

Does anyone know of a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That mean the print driver are not installed on the computer, please configure point & print restriction to allow a user to install driver that are from your printserver.

How to change the Point and Print Restrictions policies setting

1.Open the Group Policy Management Console (GPMC).

2.In the GPMC console tree, navigate to the domain or organizational unit (OU) that stores the user accounts for which you want to modify printer driver security settings.

3.Right-click the appropriate domain or OU, click Create a GPO in this domain, and Link it here, type a name for the new GPO, and then click OK.

4.Right-click the GPO that you created, and then click Edit.

5.In the Group Policy Management Editor window, click Computer Configuration, click Policies, click Administrative Templates, and then click Printers.

6.Right-click Point and Print Restrictions, and then click Edit.

**How to permit users to connect only to specific print servers that you trust**

1.In the Point and Print Restrictions dialog box, click Enabled.

**Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers : Point and Print Restrictions**

Setting: Enabled

2.Click to select the Users can only point and print to these servers check box if it is not already selected.

3.In the text box, type the fully qualified server names to which you want to allow users to connect. Separate each name by using a semicolon (;).

4.In the When installing drivers for a new connection box, select Do not show warning or elevation prompt.

5.In the When updating drivers for an existing connection box, select Show warning only.

6.Click OK.